# RoR: How can i use a variable from one action to another inside the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller i have two actions: `"Select_users"` and `"Make_something"`.
In "Select_users" i get a `@var` with a list of users (this users are generated from a search with a form in the same view) and i need to make an insert for each of those ... like:

```
   @var.each do |v|
     Table.create(:atribute => v.name)
   end
```

When i have my list of selected users i use a Submit button to send me to the "Make_something" action.

So i was thinking to "pass" the @var variable to the "Make_something" action to make this create, but I can't use @var in "Make_something" because it's accesible only in "Select_users".

I read about filters but i think they cant help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your actual controller code. It's very difficult to follow in just paraphrasing.

Comment: user1054152, look at @Pavling's answer -- the others could mislead you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have code common to several methods, extract it out to another method.

```
def select_users
  @var = go_get_those_users
end

def make_something
  go_get_those_users.each do |v| Table.create(:atribute => v.name) end
end

private
def go_get_those_users
  # do whatever you need to populate your collection
  return [] 
end
```

Alternatively, you could pass the list of IDs of the selected users in the form that posts to "make_something". Or if you *really* want to persist this somehow (I assume this is some form of "multi-step form wizard" of some description), user the db, not the session - have a "wizard" model that is retained in the DB. Each step would then pass the wizard_id, and save its own values to the wizard - this could have normal AR associations (for your selected users) through relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, finally i saved search's parameters in session[] and repeat the method search users in both other methods.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of **[before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)**. Add the below code before any action definition i.e after class difinition.

```
before_filter :initialize_variable, :only => [:select_users, :make_something]
```

this will make sure that the `method` `initialize_variable` is `called` `whenever` any of those other `methods` called and it will `initialize` the `variable` like below. And then you can use the variable directly.

```
def initialize_variable
  @required_var = // get the details
end
```

**USAGES:**

```
def select_users
  @required_var.each //......
end
```

and

```
def make_something
   @required_var.each //......
end
```

Comment: Please... don't do this as you'll end up with broken code (stale objects in sessions will cause all sorts of unexpected problems), and future developers of the code will curse you for using such a bodge

Comment: That's quite an edit ;-) Yes - much better to not use the session as a dumping ground for variables

Answer (score 0):

How can you guarantee that one action will be run before the other.

If you want that data to persist for a particular user then save it in a model.

Maybe have a `wizard` model with the user_id and fields for the various steps.

if you want it persisted in just that session then use `session[:something]`

Check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model